# If you assign Javascript to a button that is already issuing a redirect, does that script get executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb, jquery-events

**Update**

I figured out that Turbolinks causes links within your application to load content asynchronously, so `$(document).ready()` only fires on the first page you visit. Therefore, adding jQuery turbolinks gem solves the page refresh part of this problem. The JS failing to execute on a different view though is still unresolved.

I have a JS function that refuses to work correctly in a Rails 4 project where I am using Foundation 5. The JS seems syntactically fine and the way I am laying out my files seem fine too. However, The divs targeted in my function are behaving strangely. The more I looked into it, the more confused I got with how Javascript gets passed around in Rails so I thought I'd ask here.

The setup is I have the JS function located in a `scripts.js` file which is located in `app/assets/javascripts`. My `application.js` file is including `//= require_tree .` which should include all my script files I believe.

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .
$(function() {
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

**scripts.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide after div by default
    $('#after-review').hide();
    $('.instruction #after-review').hide();
    $(".form-actions.review-create .button").on("click", function() {
      alert("I am an alert box!");
      $('#before-review').hide();
      $('#after-review').show();
      $('.instruction #after-review').show();
    });
});
```

I am fairly confident that the function itself is syntactically fine. It's a simple one that just hides and shows two divs. Here is where it gets confusing for me though. When I visit the page where the `$('#after-review').hide();` div is supposed to be hidden initially, it isn't hidden...until I refresh the page that is.

For some reason the JS doesn't seem to hide the div on page load. Also, when I click the button that is supposed to trigger the event, nothing happens. The submit button redirects from the form, back to the show page like it is meant to but the divs do not hide/show.

**1 - Why do I need to refresh the page in order for the divs to be hidden. (I resolved this already)**

**2 - Why won't the divs hide/show when I click the button? It is actually a similar situation here in that I need to refresh the page before any JS is triggered. Even then, when I click the button, the `alert("I am an alert box!");` is triggered.** but nothing else is triggered.

The only thing that comes to mind as a potential problem is maybe because the page where the button is and the page where the divs are supposed to do the hide/show are in two separate views. I know that you can't execute Javascript on a redirect but the script is just show/hiding divs. So, I am wondering if it will run the JS and show/hide those divs even though the dis are not on that same page where the JS is getting executed.

**_form.html.erb**

```
  <div class="form-actions review-create">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => "tiny round button" %>
  </div>
```

**Rendered button erb markup in browser**

```
  <div class="form-actions review-create">
    <input class="button tiny round button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Review">
  </div>
```

**show.html.erb (where the show/hide divs are located)**

```
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <div id="before-review">
        <h4></h4>
      </div>
      <div id="after-review">
        <h4>Things and stuff, things and more stuff.</h4>
      </div>
```

I am happy to provide any info that would be helpful. I'd really like to understand this.

Comment: Binding with `$(selector).on(...)` only works if the element exists on page load, and with turbolinks it probably won't unless you reload the page. As a result, you should bind with `$(document).on('click', ".form-actions.review-create .button", function() { ... });` outside of any `$(document).ready()` calls. This will watch the document for clicks always, and if the click happened to come from `'.form-actions.review-create .button'` it will run the function.

Comment: @ptd That is a great answer, thank you! Still, the function won't work because the divs I am trying to manipulate in the function are in a different view than the event handler. I think I will need to use jQuery to pass a cookie that store whether I submitted a review or not. Then, I can then use that to trigger an if statement in an erb tag to display the correct div.

Comment: As it turns out, I decided to use tooltips because it is a much better way to accomplish what I am trying to do. However, handling events in different views is something I'd love to learn more about so I am glad I got stuck on this problem. Now, it got me researching and learning about it which is great! I'll post my findings once I can create a test case. Anyone else by all means, feel free to share if you've tackled this problem as well!